# White space overlay on UI Webview Xcode

Tags: xcode

I dragged the UI Webview to the layout. Why It has a white space overlay on the web view text? What is that?

[Click to see the problem (Photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOl6G.jpg)

Comment: This seems to be a UI bug in Xcode. Load the inspector again and see if the problem persists.

Comment: just try to quit xcode and relaunch it

Comment: relaunch already, Not working..